# combinatorics problems on number of ways a student can answer a a paper of two sections .

Tags: combinatorics

A question paper is split into two parts – part $A$ and part $B$. Part $A$ contains $5$ questions and part $B$ has $4$ questions. Each question in part $A$ has an alternative. A student has to attempt at least one question from each part. Find the number of ways in which the student can attempt the question paper.

This question tells that part $A$ has $5$ question with an alternative. does that mean that we have $10$ or $5$ question to choose from . 
for part $A$ should I choose the number of ways as $(\binom{10}1 + \binom{10}2 + \binom{10}3 + \binom{10}4 + \binom{10}5)$ or $(\binom51 + \binom52 + \binom53 + \binom54 + \binom55)$.

Comment: I think the instructions are unclear. Consider question A1 and its "alternative" A1a. I *think* it means a student can attempt one or the other, but not both. So I would count $3^5-1$ ways of completing part A.

Comment: The way I read this there are five questions in part A.  For each such question, there are two versions.  Thus, if you pick a question from part A, you have two choices of which version you answer.  However, the way it reads, I don't think you can answer both versions of the same question and count them as two of the five questions you can answer.

Comment: Any thoughts, lamdeb?

Comment: Earth to lamdeb, come in, please.

Comment: I am sorry ,I did not see your comment as i had gone out .. I haven't understood why you chose the 3^5 instead of 2^5 and why the -1 . the question already tells that the student must pick at least 1 question . so there is no way where he cannot pick no question.

Comment: For the first question on Part A, you have three options: answer the question, answer the alternative, or neither. Same for the second, ..., fifth questions. That's where $3^5$ comes from. But you can't take the "neither" option on all five questions, so that's where the $-1$ comes from. OK? By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it somewhere.